# How to fix this "Sorry <1> is not a valid option" in GRASS-Ubuntu using r.water.outlet?

Tags: grass-gis, error, loop, watershed, grass.script

I am working with this .sh code (a while loop, extracted from: http://www.surfaces.co.il/) to create watersheds from drainage raster and outlet point of every watershed, but I obtain this error: "Sorry <1> is not a valid option", "Sorry <2> is not a valid option" and so on.

```
i=0   #an iterator to give consecutive names to the new watersheds
while read X Y; do 
    i=$(( i + 1 ))  
    r.water.outlet drainage=fdir basin=wshed$i easting=$X northing=$Y --overwrite 
    echo "$X"
    echo "$Y"
    #r.null -q wshed_$i setnull=0 
    r.to.vect -s in=wshed$i out=wshed$i feature=area --overwrite 
    #g.remove rast=wshed_$i
done < cross_points.txt
echo "Created $i catchments"
```

Comment: What does your cross_points.txt look like? Also, in case you are not already aware: each X,Y must fall **exactly** on a drainage line.

Comment: @Micha I created with: v.out.ascii in=points out=cross_points.txt format=point fs=space --overwrite

Comment: Two more ideas: I think that v.out.ascii adds a third column with the cat value. So you'll have to add to your "while read" like so: while read X Y cat; do.... Also you might need to quote the variable $i as ${i}.

Comment: @Micha Yes, you are right. If you want to answer the question, I will support it.

Comment: Generally, consider also to first run echo "...", then call r.water.outlet to see what goes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that your point text file was created with v.out.ascii. That module adds a third column with the cat value. So you'll have to add to your "while read" loop like so (even though you don't need the cat value):

`while read X Y cat; do....`